# Type inference with the same constructor

Tags: f#, type-inference

I am writing a small F# program.

```
type type_a= | T of int | S of string;;
let aa=T 30;;
type type_b= | T of int | S of string;;
let bb =T 40;;
```

Above, why how does the compiler distinguish the type for aa and bb? The interactive console from Visual Studio thinks bb is of type type_b, aa is of type type_a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your discriminated unions are exposing T and S.
When calling `let aa=T 30` `type_b` is not known yet so compiler is infering T from `type_a`.
On next line `type_b` is defined and so `T` and `S` from `type_b` are now shadowing `T` and `S` from `type_a`. All subsequent call to `T` is infered to `type_b`.

You can still reference `T` from `type_a` unsing `let cc=type_a.T 50;;` in the rest of your code.